# Dynamically resizing a UILabel, but its not working.

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, ios4, ios6

I am trying to re-size a label according to text in it (or max width I am allowing i.e.108) and place a button just next to it, code below is actually giving satisfying results while debugging but width of label is not changing accordingly.
Is there any special settings to do in an xib or any thing else **please help Iam**.

```
        NSDictionary *attrib=@{NSFontAttributeName:locFeedcell.lbl_location.font};
        CGFloat width=[locFeedcell.lbl_location.text sizeWithAttributes:attrib].width;
        CGRect newLabelframe=locFeedcell.lbl_location.frame;
        CGRect newButtonFrame=locFeedcell.btn_map.frame;
        if (width>=108.00f) {
            newLabelframe.size.width=108.00;
        } else {
            newLabelframe.size.width=width;
            newButtonFrame.origin.x=locFeedcell.lbl_location.bounds.origin.x+width+4.00;
        }
        locFeedcell.lbl_location.frame=newLabelframe;
        locFeedcell.btn_map.frame=newButtonFrame;
```

here is snapshot of xib file.

[image: here is snapshot of xib file.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** Instead of using `locFeedcell.lbl_location.bounds.origin.x+width` use `locFeedcell.lbl_location.frame.origin.x+width`. `bounds.origin.x` is always `0`.

Maybe Auto Layout is enabled in your `.xib` file? Check the file inspector tab in the utilities pane. 
If this doesn't help, can you post the values for the frame before and after you set them? Remember the memory address for your label and button and print their frames again after everything is laid out.

A quick tip:
You can use `CGRectGetMaxX(locFeedcell.lbl_location.frame)` instead of `locFeedcell.lbl_location.bounds.origin.x+width` to get the right edge from the frame.

Comment: yes the auto layout was enabled, didn't knew about that. Thanx that was a huge help. And thanx for the tip too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any logic problem in your code. There are two things you may have a check:

1. Change the maximum width to twice or more wider to make the change noticeable, so it can be easier verified;
2. Make sure you are in UI thread when you set new frame to UI elements.

Comment: it is actually verified by me as i say i verified it through debugging points.

Answer (score 0):

What about using Autolayout constraints?

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

You have 3 objects:

1. was recently at --> let's call it lbl_recentlyAt
2. lbl_location
3. btn_map

You will need 3 constraints:

1. Set the fix position of your recently add label:

> |-X-[lbl_recentlyAt]

1. Set the variable position of the location label and the button, let's say with 20p space

> [lbl_recentlyAt]-20-[lbl_location]-20-[btn_map]

You may need to call setNeedsLayout method of your cell when the lbl_location width changes to update the layout: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/setNeedsLayout

```
[cellView setNeedsLayout]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: auto layout do helps but i was trying to do it the easy way... using auto layot is a complex thing for me... but thnkyou **@adepablor** for the knowledge share. It may help me somewhere in future.

Comment: You are welcome, use any approach you think is easier for you. But my suggestion is, now or in the foreseeable future, to read carefully the autolayout link I posted. It will take you no more than an hour and you will see it is not that complex! Also, you can add constraints in storyboards which means less code which means less bugs, it is great! :)

Answer (score 0):

//use this for custom font

CGFloat width =  [label.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ChaparralPro-Bold" size:40 ]].width;

//use this for system font

CGFloat width =  [label.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:40 ]].width;

label.frame = CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, width,height);

//point.x, point.y -> origin for label;

//height -> your label height;